# Prism: Get target view in ConfirmNavigationRequest

Tags: wpf, navigation, prism

Prism allows to decide if a navigation request can be performed by using the IConfirmNavigationRequest interface. With this the ConfirmNavigationRequest method is called before the view is replaced by another in the same region.

I want to use this method to decide where ever the use can navigate based on the target. So if the user just opens the settings view, every thing is fine and he can navigate, but if he want to switch to the reporting page before he has selected some data than I have to open a message box telling him, that he has to select the data.

How can I get a reference to the new view?